# what's the difference between 'load mmc' and 'load addr'?

Tags: linux-kernel, u-boot

Here's my u-boot

```
## Booting kernel from Legacy Image at 42000000 ...
   Image Name:   Linux-4.1.8
   Image Type:   ARM Linux Kernel Image (uncompressed)
   Data Size:    3458160 Bytes = 3.3 MiB
   Load Address: 70008000
   Entry Point:  70008000
   Verifying Checksum ... OK
   Loading Kernel Image ... OK

Starting kernel ...
```

And it stuck.

what's the difference between the 42000000 and the 70008000? Should the two be the same?

Comment: Do you really think answers to your questions are going to solve the real issue of *"it stuck"*?  Why not provide the details of your board, the typical boot sequence, and what's different that it is now failing?  FWIW your uImage loaded at 0x42000000 seems to be unable to decompress (assuming that there's a zImage within that uImage, which is typical for an ARM kernel).

Answer (score 3):

```
Booting kernel from Legacy Image at 42000000 ...
```

- This first address is the one where u-boot will look for the (probably compressed) linux kernel image.

> Load Address: 70008000

- is the address where u-boot will copy the decompressed linux kernel image

> Entry Point:  70008000 - linux kernel entry point address

- Once the linux image has been decompressed and copied to the *load address* location, the entry point is the address where to start executing the kernel image, that in this case is exactly the start of the memory area where the kernel has been copied.

You can find further detail @ below link:

http://lists.denx.de/pipermail/u-boot/2007-March/020043.html

https://balau82.wordpress.com/2010/04/12/booting-linux-with-u-boot-on-qemu-arm/

Comment: This is what really confused me: the uImage is on the file system, why u-boot trying to find it on some where in the memory? 42000000 is a memory address, right?

Comment: *"This first address is the one where u-boot will look for the (probably compressed) linux kernel image."*  -- U-Boot isn't "looking" for anything.  That output line *"## Booting kernel from Legacy Image at 42000000 ..."* is the direct consequence of a **`bootm 0x42000000`** command.  In other words you (or the **bootcmd** environment variable) explicitly told U-Boot that it should ***boot*** the **uImage** at that specific memory address.